# How to add a char at the end of any word found inside a var with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to add a char at the end of any word find by regex inside a var.

i need to transform a var in json and i block when i have to add a simple double quote at the end of a word like DataTypes.INTEGER but INTEGER can be STRING or any other type. With this regex \DataTypes.\w+/g i can find any occur inside this var but i can't find the way to add this char.

Example :

```
"User":{
  "id":{
    "type":"DataTypes.INTEGER,
    "primaryKey":true,
    "allowNull":false,
    "autoIncrement":true
  },
  "name":{
    "type":"DataTypes.STRING,
    "allowNull":false
  },
  "surname":{
    "type":"DataTypes.STRING,
    "allowNull":false
  },
  "hash":{
    "type":"DataTypes.STRING,
    "allowNull":false
  },
  "email":{
    "type":"DataTypes.STRING,
    "allowNull":false
  },
  "role":{
    "type":"DataTypes.INTEGER,
    "allowNull":false
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: This looks more like an issue in creating JSON. You should fix that

Comment: Not sure what you need from reading what you wrote. Add a missing `"`? Try `replace(/("DataTypes\.[A-Z]+),/g, '$1",')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want to add the missing quotes.

```
replace(/(DataTypes\.\w+)/g, '$1"');
```

You can also try it here: https://regex101.com/r/d0a3I8/2

Comment: The dot must be escaped.

Comment: @Toto You are correct. At least it SHOULD be escaped, but it works anyway :-). Fixed it.